# Safari iframes – Blocked a frame with origin "https://ABC" from accessing a frame with origin "https://XYZ". Protocols, domains, and ports must match

Tags: iframe, safari, embed

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://AAA.BBB" from accessing
a frame with origin "https://XXX.netlify.app". Protocols, domains,
and ports must match
```

I'd like to to embed a website (that the client has designed) into a client portfolio – on Chrome there are no issues given that the two domains share the same protocol, but on Safari I am getting the above message.

AAA.BBB is the external website I am trying to embed into the netlify site.

I'm wondering why this is an issue on Safari as I've had no issues embedding a Vimeo video for example onto a different site (and obviously they share different domain/ports?)

The site is built using React & Gatsby.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I have the same problem, only safari throws a cors error saying that Protocols, domains, and ports must match.